# How can I call multiple views in one url address in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to show forms defined by new_measurement on index.html, but I only manage to get `IndexView()` to work. I tried various combinations between `IndexView()` and `new_measurement()`, but those didn't work out at all. I know that `IndexView()` doesn't pass anything related to `new_measurement()`, and `new_measurement()` isn't called, which is the core of my problem. I'd really appreciate if someone more experienced with Django could tell me what I could, or should do. Thank you.

Here's my **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Measurement
from .forms import MeasurementForm
from django.views import generic


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Measurement
    context_object_name = 'measurement_list'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    queryset = Measurement.objects.all()


def new_measurement(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MeasurementForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.measurement_date = timezone.now()
            measurement.save()
    else:
        form = MeasurementForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

**forms.py**:

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measurement
        fields = ('measurement_value', 'measurement_unit')
```

**index.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Climate Measurement Tool</h1>

    <h2>Add a new measurement</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save">Add</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Measurements</h2>
    {% if measurement_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for measurement in measurement_list %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ measurement }}</p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No measurements yet</p>
    {% endif %}    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't map multiple views in one url but you can do mutiple works in one view.
update your views.py as you can see that I am sending (querylist and form) both in that view

views.py

```
def new_measurement(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MeasurementForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.measurement_date = timezone.now()
            measurement.save()
    else:
        form = MeasurementForm()

    qs = Measurement.objects.all()
    context = {'form': form, 'measurement_list': qs}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

update urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.new_measurement, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps! How can I implement incase I want to use the class based view instead of function based view. Just opposite to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call 2 views for one url. basically each url has to be linked to one view and that's something you can't really change.

But if you want your code to be cleaner and have multiple functions, you can call them in your view, basically what you can do is to make a view and call it when a url or even more than one url has been used and in that view decide which function to use

Example:

```
def god_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST"
        return post_func(request)
    return get_func(request)
```

This is a very simple example but you can do so many other things.

Comment: I liked this solution a lot, it's very clean, but I couldn't get it to work. I got this error when calling IndeView(): __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I don't understand what's wrong since it looks good to me?

Comment: Well i don't know what your code s but it's not related to this solution. it's a simple way. if you get errors in your code you probably should check for mistakes. You're basically calling another function and returning what that function will return. Nothing complicated really.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generic.ListView you can try with ***rest_framework.views.APIView***

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class IndexView(APIView):
    
    def post(self, request: Request):
        form = MeasurementForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            measurement = form.save(commit=False)
            measurement.measurement_date = timezone.now()
            measurement.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})

    def get(self, request: Request):
        form = MeasurementForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

This gives you more control on the APIs you call. Also you can raise/return error when you call your API using incorrect methods (PUT, PATCH)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have more views in one url, but **you can simulate it**. I did it like a view and in the template of this view was javascript which loaded the second view with the response of `AJAX` and filled the belonging element with the second view's content. The second view was not whole template but it started with some `div` tags which were placed into the first template. I'll try to give you an example

**views**

```
def first_view(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'first_template.html',
        {
            'first_content': 'Some heavy content'
        })


def second_view(request):
    return render(
        request, 
        'second_template.html', 
        {
            'second_content': 'Some heavier content!'
        })
```

**first_template.html**

```
...
<body>

    <div id="1">
        {{ first_content }}
    </div>
    <div>
        ... loading ...
    </div>

    <script>

    window.onload = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: {% url 'to_second_view' %},
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#2').html(response);
            }
        })
    }

    </script>

</body>
...
```

**second_template.html**

```
<div>
    {{ second_content }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cbv you can override the `get_template_names` method for any view that inherits `TemplateResponseMixin` and return a list of string which are searched in order until one matches or `ImporperlyConfigured` is raised. For example:

```
class SomeView(TemplateResponseMixin):
   ...
   def get_template_names(self):
      if self.request.method == "POST":
         return ['post_template.html']
      else:
         return ['template.html']
```